# Move window from one desktop to another using drag and drop

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

Up until I upgraded to KDE 4.13.0, I was able to drag an application from the taskbar to a desktop in the desktop-switcher on the task-bar. This would move that window to the other desktop. This doesn't work any more.

How can I re-enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Developer blogs**

http://blogs.kde.org/2013/07/29/kde-plasma-desktop-411s-new-task-manager

> There's also some bad news (with a side dish of glimmers-of-hope)
>
> Sadly, a few features didn't make it into the new version - yet, at
>   least.
>
> One is the ability to drag tasks from the Task Manager onto the pager...

**Workaround**

A workaround is to use another task manager - earlier: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?64014-Manual-Grouping-of-Task-Panel-items-no-longer-possible

The old task manager: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?64014-Manual-Grouping-of-Task-Panel-items-no-longer-possible&p=338505&viewfull=1#post338505

The old task manager seems to work with the KDE 4.13.

PPA search: [https://www.google.fi/search?&q=plasma-widget-old-tasks+.deb+site:https://launchpad.net/](https://www.google.fi/search?&q=plasma-widget-old-tasks+.deb+site%3ahttps://launchpad.net/)